# Javascript/Jquery Lazy load not supported..How does facebook do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, facebook, lazy-loading

So I am trying to implement a basic image lazy load feature to speed up the loading of my website.  From what I understand the Jquery plugin lazyload worked for a while but is no longer supported for new browsers.

My question is simple:

How do other sites do it then?  Sites such as facebook do have support for this type of thing, so there has to be an answer out there.  I'm aware that they have full teams of developers for this sort of thing, but with all of the complexities of javascript there has to be a feasible solution.

So does anyone have a patch for the lazyload plugin or a way to do it that works?  It would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

EDIT

My previous research seemed to indicate that all of the tutorials were using the same plugin since there are many that are named similarly.  However there are many differing variations and I was unclear in my original question.

I will try to find a cross-browser solution based on the suggestions below and post it here to make this post more useful for others.

Comment: which jQuery plugin are you using? there are many! **and** what wont work on newer browsers?

Comment: Apologies, I was under the impression that there was only one, or a limited number of jquery plugins.  My research seemed to point at this fact since they all seemed to be named similarly.  Yes, it turns out there are many variations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this on for size: http://ivorycity.com/blog/2011/04/19/jquery-lazy-loader-load-html-and-images-on-scroll/

Worked fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: If it worked for you, please mark as the answer and vote up!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try Ryan Grove's LazyLoad library http://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/

Comment: Unfortunately this is only for .css or .js files.  Thanks though!